# Is there a program for Ubuntu like Proxifier, that works with all applications?

Tags: software-recommendation, proxy, tor

I'm using Tor to access blocked websites in my school (Internet access through proxy with authentication). In Windows there is software called Proxifier which routes all connections and acts like using a regular Internet connection. In Ubuntu, I'm using a combination of Tor and Privoxy. But unfortunately not all applications route connections through system proxy or have an option to apply proxy.

Is there any option like Proxifier so that it is not necessary to put proxy settings and to access the Internet in my case?

(It's so annoying that Google doesn't work most of the time in tor connections.)